# Angular binding list to another list with different property name

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting list of object by service. And these list is in result.data. 
 But the object in result.data have property "Text" and "Value". But i want to bind the list to array which has property "label" and "value". In C# we can do this by Select. And so i wrote below like c#. But how i can do in typescript with angular 6.

```
this.serviceHelper.getStudentTypes().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.studentTypes = result.data
      .Select(p => new SelectItem {//???
      label=p.Text,                //???
      value=p.Value                //???
    });
  }
);
```

selectItem.ts

```
export interface SelectItem {
    label?: string;
    value: any;
    styleClass?: string;
    icon?: string;
    title?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this virtually identically in JS/TS, you just need to use `map`, and the corect way to create a JS object literal:

```
this.serviceHelper.getStudentTypes().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.studentTypes = result.data
      .map(p => ({
          label:p.Text,                
          value:p.Value                
    }));
  }
);
```

The above code assumes `getStudentTypes` returns an `Observable<{ Text: string, Value: string }[]>` or something equivalent.

**Edit**

Since you want the type of the new array to be `SelectItem[]` you can specify it explicitly on `map` if you want (this helps with error message on some errors) but this is not required. If `this.studentTypes` is typed as `SelectItem[]` and the return of `map` is compatible with `SelectItem` then all will work as expected (since `SelectItem` is an interface and not a class we can assign any compatible object literal to a variable of this type, this is how [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) works in typescript)

The  explicit version of `map` that explicitly returns `SelectItem[]` would be:

```
this.serviceHelper.getStudentTypes().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.studentTypes = result.data
      .map<SelectItem>(p => ({
          label:p.Text,                
          value:p.Value                
    }));
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want to map to type SelectItem. @titiancernicova-dragomir

Comment: @HasanOzdemir what does `SelectItem` look like? You just new it up and set the properties in the `map` callback.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir is javascript `map` is what you want

Comment: I edited question and add selectItem interface. Can you please check it? @titiancernicova-dragomir

Comment: @HasanOzdemir You don't need any further steps since `SelectItem` is an interface, and the resulting objects satisfy it. You don't have to implement interfaces explicitly in typescript. It's enough that an object has a `value` property to be considered an instance of `SelectItem`.

Comment: Yes like javascript but the difference is i want to map to special type (SelectItem). Not to object like javascript. @RezaRahmati

Comment: I am using primeNG. And it want SelectItem array for dropdownlist. So i need mapping to SelectItem @sloth

Comment: @HasanOzdemir did you define an interface or class in javascript for that?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir edited, the answer, you don't really need to type it explicitly, typescript uses structural typing so object literals that have the properties are considered to implement the interface.

Comment: Yes. I added my interface to question. That interface is interface by automatically created by primeNg . @RezaRahmati

Comment: Thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. This is what i was looking for.